# How can I define my own colors in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I want to use my own color scheme in the plots I create with matplotlib.

1. For instance, if I do

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()

plt.plot(np.arange(5), rng.random((5)))
plt.plot(np.arange(5), rng.random((5)))
plt.show()
```

I want the lines to be my custom colors, rather than the default blue, orange, etc.

2. I would also like for my custom defined colors to have names, so that I can do `plt.plot(np.arange(5), rng.random((5)), color='my_color_1')`.

---

Reading [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#using-style-sheets), I figured it might be possible to create a style file and using the following at the top of my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.set("/path/to/your/file.mplstyle")
```

To get point #1, I can create a style file containing e.g.

```
axes.prop_cycle : cycler('color', ['4165c0', 'e770a2', '5ac3be', '696969'])
```

However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do #2. The [examples presented in the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#defining-your-own-style) are only related to the size of various elements, and I haven't found any other repositories that do something similar.

---

Is it possible to use a style file to define my own named color scheme? If so, how? If not, is there another way to do it?